# How to have admin privileges to the RavenDB web UI

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm running Raven.Server.exe from stable build 2261. I'm able to access the raven studio from localhost:8080 but I'm not able to perform many operations (like create a database). When I try, Windows authentication pops up asking for my credentials. I'm running as administrator in the same computer but my credentials are not recognized. The same thing happens using embedded mode. Only by putting the application on IIS was I able to use the raven studio as an admin. But I want to be able to do it using the console-based server and/or the embedded mode. Please help.

Asp .net mvc 4 app config:

```
RavenController.Store = new DocumentStore 
{ 
    ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"
}

<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080;" />
```

Raven.Server.exe.config:

```
<add key="Raven/Port" value="*"/>
<add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Database\System"/>
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

Check out these screenshots describing the problem step-by-step:

http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issueImageAttachments?issue=57-1412

Comment: What build are you using? 
Are you running on a domain?
Is the user you are trying to log in as is an admin?
Does the user that ravendb runs as has admin privileges?

Comment: Build 2261, Running on my home machine so no domain, I'm the admin of my machine (but haven't configured any users for raven), RavenDB is running in the same machine so it has admin priveleges.

Thanks for taking the time to help me out man.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of "Raven/AnonymousAccess" to "Admin".

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
```

This is probably a terrible idea for production. But should do the trick when running in console mode for development.